# How To Create A Purge Command With Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I can't figure out how to create the purge command in discord.py. This is what I am currently using it creates no errors in the code but the bot doesn't respond to the command.

```
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.content.startswith('!purge'):
    tmp = await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Clearing messages...')
    async for msg in client.logs_from(message.channel):
        await client.delete_message(msg)
```

Comment: Is `on_message` being called?  Try sprinkling some `print`s in there to see the path the execution is taking.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it you're using the async branch (please switch to [rewrite](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/migrating.html#migrating-to-v1-0)) of discord.py

For one doing the whole command invocation in `on_message` thing is not, while it works, a good way of doing it. Try out the [commands extension](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/examples/basic_bot.py)!

Secondly there is already a method for this in async see [here](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.purge_from)

Thirdly the reason why your code isn't working or why it doesn't look like it's working is because you are using `client.logs_from` with no limit specified so it's downloading every message in that channel and this will take a while to do before it executes the code below it.